# OpenWrt: White listing all IPs of a domain:

Tags: openwrt

I am trying to white-list a domain in openwrt, but seems domain is having multiple IPs.

Some devices do not get access to white-listed domain may be because they already carry an entry in host file for white-listed domain, which suppresses need for new dns lookups and hence the entry in host file becomes a stale entry.

**How can I ensure all IPs are getting whitelisted for a domain.**
I tried putting domains in both HS_UAMALLOW and HS_UAMDOMAINS.

Ex: I am white-listing facebook.com. Not all user are able to access facebook from my router

Answer (score 0):

You can install transparent proxy server (for instance Squid) which supports black\white lists by domain